# Magento SOAP API v1 in browser

Tags: magento-1.9, soap-api-v1

When querying through a web browser the old SOAP API of a magento 1.9, Apache get mad, with the following:

```
http://www.fld.fr/index.php/api/soap/index/?wsdl=1

[negotiation:error] [pid 9289] [client 127.0.0.1:58231] AH00687: Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /my/magento/root/api (None could be negotiated).
[negotiation:error] [pid 9286] [client 127.0.0.1:58232] AH00687: Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /my/magento/root/api (None could be negotiated).
[negotiation:error] [pid 9281] [client 127.0.0.1:58233] AH00687: Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /my/magento/root/api (None could be negotiated).
[negotiation:error] [pid 9290] [client 127.0.0.1:58234] AH00687: Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /my/magento/root/api (None could be negotiated).
```

Atop of these line is a similar one, showing the external IP that triggered the SOAP call, all the others dealing 127.0.0.1 (and some PID changes).
Did the soap api v1 become a fork bomb when queried in web browser?

This has been only seen on Magento 1.9; it works fine on 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: I had a redirection (between store views) custom module that caused the fork bomb.

Magento works perfectly and its soap api are fine.

Comment: Not the very same day that I post the answer, I have to wait tomorrow